# Solution for this inheritance problem in composition

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, composition

I have a python concrete class

```
class base
    def a():
        pass
    def b():
        pass
    def c():
        pass
    .
    .
    def z():
        pass
```

I want to have the n number of similar classes with same set of methods but different implementations(hardly differ by 3-4 methods)

Since i want to reuse the code, i am considering inheritance

```
class child1(base):
    def b():
        pass
    def c():
        pass

class child2(base):
    def g():
        pass
    def z():
        pass
    def i():
        pass
    def j():
        pass

class child3(base):
    def b():
        pass
```

**Question:**
It is not violating the liskov substitution principle as the preconditons and post conditions are same.
But i would like not to use inheritance
How can this be achieved with composition so that we can maximize the reusability? is it something like this

```
#abstract class
class a:
    def foo()

class a1(a):
    def foo():
        pass

class a2(a):
     def foo():
         pass

#abstract class
class b:
    def foo()

class b1(b):
    def foo():
        pass

class child1:
    obj1 = a2()
    obj2 = b1()
    .
    .
    obj3 = z5()

    def a():
        obj1.foo()
    .
    .
    def z():
        obj26.foo()
```

For the above approach i need far more classes and logic to factory logic to create their objects. if i add more child classes does this scale well.
or do i even require classes for this problem? Any other python way to solve this?

Comment: Please post valid Python code. `//` is not a comment in Python, nor are vertical dots. (If you want to indicate an arbitrary block of code, a lone ellipsis (`...`) *is* a valid statement by itself. And a comment by itself is not a valid function body; use pass.

Comment: This is not something you can generalize. Whether you use inheretence or composition depends on whether the class **is** something or merely **uses** it. Addition **is** an operation while a HttpClient **uses** a connection even if they share a part of the interface.

Comment: Without knowing anything about your class or what these methods are supposed to be doing, it is impossible to know if you are violating the Liskov substitution principle.  Computer Science is an art, not a science.

Comment: It looks like your classes are just used as collections for some methods. Is this correct?

Comment: @Wups The problem here I have a common interface and implementations are different, Most of the methods have same implementation except for few. Assuming that preconditions and post conditions are same, does it violate liskov substitution principle to use inheritance and override the methods of implemented classes in child classes

Answer (score 1):

Here is one suggestion, if you don't want to use inheritance:

```
# implementations of all methods:
def a1():
    print("a1")
def a2():
    print("a2")
def b1():
    print("b1")
def b2():
    print("b2")

# only one class needed
class Flexi:
    def __init__(self, funcs):
        for name, func in funcs.items():
            setattr(self, name, func)
    def a(self):
        pass
    def b(self):
        pass
```

Then, construct a Flexi instance with a combination of methods in some kind of factory:

```
def create_flexi():
    funcs = {"a": a2, "b": b1}
    return Flexi(funcs)

example = create_flexi()
example.a()
example.b()
```